# Change active tab color in nautilus

Tags: unity, nautilus, gtk3, css

I have the Ambiance-Dark theme installed on Ubuntu 14.04 and I'm not satisfied with the tab colors of Nautilus tabs. The active/inactive tab colors are pretty much identical, so it's very difficult to understand on which tab I am on.

I'd like to increase the contrast between them (hopefully in a more firefox-ish way), but I don't know what I have to modify. I already looked into the `/usr/share/themes/Ambiance-Dark/gtk-3.0/apps/nautilus.css` but it doesn't seem to have any entry for this.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know much about the specifics of Nautilus and their CSS, but overall the `.css` file only has things that are styled specifically, so the color of the tabs is probably defaulting from some other system property.

Try creating a rule for the `.tab` class and setting it's background color to something exotic to test:

```
.tab {
    background-color: red !important;
}
```